# Under what circumstances does a reactJS component unmount?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to diagnose an error:

Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.

I am placing a log message as follows:

```
  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('unmounting ', this.props.fieldName)
  }
```

and thus I can see that my component is unmounting.

But *why is it unmounting*? Under what circumstances does a component unmount.

If I know all the possibloe circumstances under which a component unmounts then I can trace the error down and fix it.

Comment: It is difficult to say what the error is due to without the code that produces it.

Comment: It could be due to a version change including the deprecation of `isMounted`. Maybe [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/67f8524e88abbf1ac0fd86d38a0477d11fbc7b3e/docs/_posts/2015-12-16-ismounted-antipattern.md) helps.

Comment: Maybe there is something going on in a parent component, which leads to unmounting your component? Also I think React sometimes does unmount and remount a component instead of updating it (because there is too much to update?). Anyway, I haven't found a good documentation about this but would also be interested in a proper explanation.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html, whenever the root elements have different types, react decides to tear down the old tree and build the new tree from scratch.

componentWillUnmount() will be fired during tear-down of a tree, because old DOM nodes are being destroyed.
This also applies to any nodes below the root, they will all get unmounted.